Cannot download file when using selenium Chrome webdriver with option prompt_for_download=False in Windows OS
The download error from webdriver's browser

The code I run
from selenium import webdriver  # pip install selenium
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager  # pip install webdriver-manager
 
o = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
o.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
  'download.default_directory'        : 'C:\mydownload', # change default directory for downloads
  'download.prompt_for_download'      : False, # to auto download the file
  'download.directory_upgrade'        : True,
  'plugins.always_open_pdf_externally': True # it will not show PDF directly in chrome
})
wd = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=o)
wd.get('https://file-examples.com/wp-content/storage/2017/10/file-sample_150kB.pdf')
# wd.quit()  # omit this line to see the error in the webdriver's browser

The code can run on my colleagues' macbook laptop; though fails on my Windows laptop.
What should I do to get it run succeed?
p.s.
Opening the same link manually in Chrome browser can download the file. It fails with Chrome webdriver only.

dont you get error on python run code ?

no error on python run code - my colleague on macbook can succeed with same code, and mine failed as a Windows laptop

Thanks @KJ. I will use a no-redirect sample link for the download
